# Properly implementing the Parsley.js Custom Remote Validator in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, parsley.js

I am trying to get data-parsley to validate if the username already exists in the database.

The first problem I have is how to set the JSON data to dynamically include the 'value' as the user types. Should I implement this using jQuery?

**_system_account.erb**

```
<%=
    text_field_tag("access[username]",
                   value = nil,
                   options = {:"data-parsley-remote" => "" ,
                              :"data-parsley-remote-options" => "{ 'type': 'POST', 'dataType': 'json', 'data': { ':username': 'value' }}",
                              :"data-parsley-remote-validator" => "validate-username",
                              id:"username", placeholder:  t('access.simple_username'),
                              required: "required", pattern: "[a-z0-9_-]{3,64}$",
                              :"data-parsley-trigger" => "keyup",
                              :"data-parsley-minlength"=>"3" ,
                              :"data-parsley-maxlength"=>"64"})
%>
```

The associated javascript triggers when there is a change in the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#username').bind('input propertychange', function()
    {
        window.Parsley.addAsyncValidator('validate-username', function (xhr) {
            // console.log(this.$element);
            // jQuery Object[ input[name="q"] ]
            var response = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
            alert( JSON.stringify(response) );

            // Second Problem: How do I make data-parsley identify it is an error and mark the field red or something

        }, '/application/check_username_exists');
    }); </script>
```

**application_controller.erb**

This simply checks if the username exists or not.

```
  def check_username_exists
    username_exists = Access.exists?(username: params[:username])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {:"exists" => username_exists}.to_json }
      format.html
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is populated by parsley, so remove the `data: { ':username': 'value' }`.

Since you have control on the user side, the easiest is to use the response status:

```
status = Access.exists?(username: params[:username]) ?  :unauthorized : :ok
render nothing: true, status: status
```

Invalid status (like unauthorized = 401) are for invalid fields, ...

Comment: getting output from controller: "Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)" but unable to get output from javascript; how can i alert(); whatever is the status code?

Comment: You can look at the 'network' tab (in Chrome's dev tools) and you'll have the Response headers. Good luck

Comment: forgot to use double params " params[:access][:username]"